# My friend said to me, "Please send me the pictures of myself that you clicked yesterday" . Is the use of 'myself ' correct here?

Tags: sentence-construction

I took pictures of my friend the previous day. The next day she said the above sentence. Shouldn't she have said, "Please send me the pictures **of me** that you clicked yesterday" ?

Comment: You are correct. **me** is the right pronoun there.

Comment: But she might have added, "....because I have no pictures of myself".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In American English (AmE)  I would say this as

> Please send me the pictures of me that you took  yesterday.

So, yes, in AmE *me* is correct. I think *took* is the most common or ordinary verb used here, while others such as 'snapped' are less common (although I don't think I've ever said 'clicked').